# Can I select again from element variable in Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I just started using Cheerio. How can I select again from a loop element?

```js
const championBox = $('div.css-1s4j24f>div');
championBox.each(async function(index, element) {
    console.log(
    // I want to get element>div.something>span.somethingelse
    )
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find`, it is the cheerio equivalent of `.querySelectorAll`.
Using `>` at the start of the string makes it behave like `element > div.something ...`

```js
const championBox = $('div.css-1s4j24f>div');
championBox.each(async function(index, element) {
    console.log(
        $(element).find('>div.something>span.somethingelse')
    )
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I found it on my own, but thank you for your time! Hope your post will help other people too.

Answer (score 1):

```
const championBox = $('div.css-1s4j24f>div');
championBox.each(async function(index, element) {
    const result = $(element).find('div.something>span.somethingelse');
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope this will help other people too, even if I found it by myself in the end.